# Printing lists in the same line

Tags: python-2.7

I have an output of a python code as:

```
(1,"triangle","yellow")
(2,"square","green")
```

How can I get the output below?

```
[(1,"triangle","yellow"),(2,"square","green")]
```

Comment: Could you please explain the question a little bit more?

Comment: Appended the elements one by one to a tuple and got the output. Thanks